# problem about dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

first of all i am a beginner...so please bear me.....
i have installed ubuntu 14.04 while windows 7 already installed at this point everything is ok but problem begin when i installed windows 8.1; now only two operating systems seen me (windows 7 and 8.1) but i want to use ubuntu 14.04 . now i have deleted windows 8.1 but my system shows only windows 7 while starting .....how can i get back ubuntu 14.04 please help me.

Comment: thanx sir for your concern...                                   its worked but now windows 8 loader is shown twice at startup .how can it'll be fix .

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed Windows 8.1, Windows do not search for other OS. It Only search for Windows.

So it has suppressed the GRUB. You need to reinstall GRUB using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool or you can reinstall your GRUB using Ubuntu cd running in live mode. [See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)